# Python pandas - separate string by comma unless followed by a space

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has general structure and I want to split, call df

```
[target:2,targettwo:3,name:stars, the sun,colour=blue]
[target:2,targettwo:3,name:planet, mars,colour=red]
[target:2,targettwo:4,name:neptune,colour=blue]
```

I can split using commas

```
df1=df[0].str.split(",", expand=True)
```

but this has issues with the number of columns as I don't want to split at every comma, only those without a space immediately following them.

I'm not sure on the syntax for excluding following space. Hopefully this question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a regular expression (regex) to split the strings in your dataframe column. The regular expression for a comma not followed by a space is ,(?!\s).

```
df1 = df[0].str.split(",(?!\s)", expand=True)
```

This will split the strings in your dataframe column on commas that are not immediately followed by a space.

If you want to exclude commas that are not immediately preceded by a space too, you can use (?<=\S),(?=\S) as the regular expression:

```
df1 = df[0].str.split("(?<=\S),(?=\S)", expand=True)
```

These two regular expressions utilize the concept of positive lookahead (?=...) and positive lookbehind (?<=...), which are regex techniques for looking ahead or behind the current match without including it in the result.

Comment: I like the first solution, very elegant and works a charm. Once each has been split successfully all columns are type object... is there a way to get pandas to auto update the type of each of the columns? e.g. target should be int, name should be string, etc

Answer (score 0):

The given input is ambiguous but you can still try this :

```
df1 = df[0].str.strip("[]").str.split(",(?=\S)", expand=True)
```

Output :

```
print(df1)
          0            1                    2            3
0  target:2  targettwo:3  name:stars, the sun  colour=blue
1  target:2  targettwo:3    name:planet, mars   colour=red
2  target:2  targettwo:4         name:neptune  colour=blue
```

Or this :

```
df1 = (
    df[0].str.strip("[]")
         .str.extractall(r"([^,:=]+?)[:=]([^:=]+)(?=\b,\b|$)")
         .reset_index(drop=True).groupby(0, sort=False).agg(list)
         .T.pipe(lambda x: x.explode(list(x))).reset_index(drop=True)
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df1)

  target targettwo            name colour
0      2         3  stars, the sun   blue
1      2         3    planet, mars    red
2      2         4         neptune   blue
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {0: ['[target:2,targettwo:3,name:stars, the sun,colour=blue]',
         '[target:2,targettwo:3,name:planet, mars,colour=red]',
         '[target:2,targettwo:4,name:neptune,colour=blue]']}
)
```

Comment: I like the first solution, very elegant and works a charm.

Once each has been split successfully all columns are type object... is there a way to get pandas to auto update  the type of each of the columns? e.g. target should be int, name should be string, etc